# how can I display the current ref value in my button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use useRef instead of useState. But my btn name not changing. Why ?

```
  const data = useRef(null);

  const handlePressCategory = (category: Categories) => {
    data.current = category;
    modalCategoriesRef.current?.close();
  }

        <Pressable style={[ButtonStyles.full_without, s.btn]} onPress={handleOpenModalCategories}>
          <Text style={s.btnText}>{ data.current === null ? 'Kategorie auswählen' : data.current}</Text>
        </Pressable>
```

I am very thankful for your help and answers. I dont know why its not displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing data with `useRef` doesn't trigger React to re-render your views. Think about it like some field in class that you can change without any reaction.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

If you need re-render view when your `ref` have changes, just use `useState`. It's designed specially for it

Otherwise, if it's not possible, you can write some `useForceRerender` hook that will invoke render of your component. Something like that:

```
export const useForceRerender = () => React.useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0)[1];

const App = () => {
  const data = useRef(null);
  const forceRerender = useForceRerender();

  const handlePressCategory = (category: Categories) => {
    data.current = category;
    modalCategoriesRef.current?.close();
    
    forceRerender(); // <-- here
  }

  return (
    <Pressable style={[ButtonStyles.full_without, s.btn]} onPress={handleOpenModalCategories}>
      <Text style={s.btnText}>{ data.current === null ? 'Kategorie auswählen' : data.current}</Text>
    </Pressable>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks but then I can easily use useState or not ?

Comment: Yes, of course. useState designed specially for re-render your views on state changes